# Using different relationships in an iterative function

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to use different relationships within the same iterative function.

What I need is the below calculation, however where the `all('Invoice Line');all('Purchase Order')` only is applied to `[Finished demand per bag]`

```
`calculate(sumx(mainReseptitSQL;mainReseptitSQL[Finished demand per bag]*([CM Kg price after reduced]/[CM Yield])*[CM Sold No of Bags]);all('Invoice Line');all('Purchase Order')`
```

I tried to solve it by dividing it up into another measure, where I have the filter context, see below

```
CM Finished demand per bag = calculate(sumX(mainReseptitSQL;mainReseptitSQL[Finished demand per bag]);all('Purchase Order');all('Invoice Line'))
```

Then I nested it so it looked like this.

```
TEST CM Total Cost Sold Bags = calculate(sumx(mainReseptitSQL;mainReseptitSQL[CM Finished demand per bag]*([CM Kg price after reduced]/[cm Yield])*[CM Sold No of Bags]))
```

Comment: So you want to said that `Finished demand per bag` is constant in your calculation, then but it in a variable

Comment: I just edited my question, because I tried another solution, but it didn't work.
If I was to use it in a variable, what would it look like?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to calculate `Finished demand per bag` using a specific filters, so you can put it in a variable:

```
TEST CM Total Cost Sold Bags = 
var Finished_demand_per_bag = caculate(sumx(mainReseptitSQL;mainReseptitSQL[Finished demand per bag];all('Invoice Line');all('Purchase Order'))

return 
 sumx(mainReseptitSQL;Finished_demand_per_bag *([CM Kg price after reduced]/[CM Yield])*[CM Sold No of Bags]))
```

Comment: This didn't work, it returned the same answer as my attempted solution.
It seems like the filtercontext added in the variable is removed when used in the return.

I really can't grasp this. Because all individually, added in different columns return values

Comment: Try return the variable and see if the value returned is what you seek, it should be the same value in all lines

Comment: I tried exactly that and it doesn't

Comment: It means that you have other filters applied other then `Invoice Line` and `Purchase Order`